# multiprocessing compatibility issue with Gurobi

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, gurobi

The following simple multiprocessing of a square function works fine:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

class A(object):

    def square(self, x):
        return x * x

    def test(self):
        pool = Pool()
        result = pool.map(self.square, range(5))
        return result
```

But when I add an initialization of a Gurobi model in the class like this,

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from gurobipy import *

class A(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.b = Model()

    def square(self, x):
        return x * x

    def test(self):
        pool = Pool()
        result = pool.map(self.square, range(5))
        return result

A().test()
```

It returns the following error:

```
File "model.pxi", line 290, in gurobipy.Model.__getattr__ (../../src/python/gurobipy.c:53411)
KeyError: '__getstate__'
```

A serial version with Gurobi works fine:

```
from gurobipy import *

class A(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.b = Model()

    def square(self, x):
        return x * x

    def test(self):
        res = [self.square(i) for i in range(5)]
        return res

A().test()
```

Comment: Using pathos cannot resolve the problem.

Comment: Doesn't surprise me. Check python's docs on what pool.map assumes (probably at least: function can be pickled/serialized) and then check gurobi's docs if those assumptions are guaranteed (probably not as observed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Gurobi API does not support sharing a single Gurobi environment across multiple processes or threads.  If you want to solve multiple modules in multiple processes or threads, you must explicitly create multiple Gurobi environments in each process or thread.

Comment: I c. A further question. If I have a main model m, and each process makes a small modification of that main model and solves it. In each process, since there is no copy constructor in Gurobi, I think we are supposed to do the m.copy(). The problem is that there is no environment argument in the copy function (it seems to copy the environment). How to handle that?

Comment: The model cannot be shared.  You cannot create the model then clone it across environments.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to do parallelization for the kind of problem I mentioned above in my comment?